# How to open access to stackoverflow?

Tags: support, firewall

I'm working in closed network at the moment. To obtain access to some work related sites I should ask administrator to add some records in firewall.
f.e. `I need an access to *microsoft.com/* via http && https.`
Is it enough to open `*stackoverflow.com/* via http && https` to access SO? Or I should include some other urls into request?